# Retrofit GET request with arrays in Query params

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

How to send GET request with query params like this?
key1=["S","I","D"]&key2=[["A","X",0],["X","Y","Z"]]

Answer (score 1):

According to [retrofit java documents](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/), you can do like below.

> Values are converted to strings using Retrofit.stringConverter(Type, Annotation[]) (or Object.toString(), if no matching string converter is installed) and then URL encoded. null values are ignored. Passing a List or array will result in a query parameter for each non-null item.

```
Array/Varargs Example:


 @GET("/friends")
 Call<ResponseBody> friends(@Query("group") String... groups);
 
 Calling with foo.friends("coworker", "bowling") yields /friends??> group=coworker&group=bowling.
```

So you can do something like this

```
@GET("/something")
Call<ResponseBody> getSomething(@Query("key1") String[] key1, 
Query("key2") String[] key2 );

foo.getSomething(key1, key2)
```

**Update** - above is the standard way to query parameters with multiple values

In order to send array as string, you can do like below

> Parameter names and values are URL encoded by default. Specify encoded=true to change this behavior.

```
@GET("/something")
 Call<ResponseBody> getSomething(@Query(value="key1", encoded=true) String key1);



Calling with foo.getSomething("['S','I','D']")) yields /something?key1=['S','I','D'].
```

Comment: Tried it this way and it returns each value with keyname on sending request. Not passing as string array

Answer (score 0):

Since retrofit doesn't recognize your custom array type, you have to consider parameters type `String`, then build your parameter like `"["S","I","D"]"` before pass to retrofit method.

For example create your parameter:

```
String parameter = "["
int arraySize = array.size()

for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
   parameter += "\"" + array.get(i) + "\"";
   if(i != arraySize - 1) {//Append ',' except last element
      parameter += ",";
   }
}
parameter += "]";
```

Output for array with 'S','I' and 'D' elements is `["S","I","D"]` String.
Now you can pass it as retrofit parameter.

Comment: I tried creating arraylist to add elements and converted it to String to pass but it does not give me the format I want.

Comment: You have to create your custom format, check updated answer.